# How to propagate an event up to handler chain (Carbon) after it handled by my custom handler?

Tags: objective-c, event-handling, macos-carbon

I need to handle a Tab key press in my application. In some conditions I want to do some stuff in my handler and suppress further event handling and in other cases I just skip and let other standard handlers to handle this event.

Here is my very simple app where I'm trying to do it.
https://github.com/prudnikov/TestGlobalShortcut/blob/master/TestGlobalShortcut/AppDelegate.m

It catches tab press but it always suppresses further event handling. I mean when I press Tab in the text editor the tab key is not inserted.

Can you advise what should I do to propagate standard event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that using `RegisterEventHotKey`.  But unless you need to receive the tab key when your app is not frontmost, you should not be using `RegisterEventHotKey`.  Use a regular Carbon Event handler, or use Cocoa event handling techniques.

Comment: You are right, I need to receive this event when my app is not frontmost. Currently I use NSEvent's `+ (id)addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: handler:` and with this solution I have exactly opposite problem — I can't stop event in case when I need to handle it. Is Carbon Event right choice for me?

Comment: No, Carbon Events are not going to let you capture keystrokes directed to other apps.  I think you may need to resort to a Quartz event tap, see `CGEventTapCreate`.